# Speed up query (~1 million rows) on a complex table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query-optimization, page-load-time

first of all thanks for your time reading this.

I'm working on a PHP web application that deals with the following data, as of right now there is noticeable time when trying to retrieve data, especially when drilling down the options. The primary options right now are VehicleType, Make, Model, Year, InternetPrice and Mileage. There will eventually be even more columns being used. Other columns from this list are being used for displaying data throughout the page, as 10 records are displayed at one instance.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DealerID` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VIN` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StockNumber` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehicleType` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Make` varchar(13) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Model` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trim` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Body` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehicleClass` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehicleCategory` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mileage` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Transmission` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EngineDisplacement` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EngineSize` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Induction` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DriveTrain` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FuelType` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FuelEconomyCity` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FuelEconomyHighway` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FuelEconomyCombined` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Doors` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OEMColorCodeExterior` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OEMColorCodeInterior` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OEMColorNameExterior` varchar(49) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OEMColorNameInterior` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GenericColorExterior` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GenericColorInterior` varchar(38) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InternetPrice` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ComparisonPrice` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WholeSalePrice` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MSRP` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InternetSpecial` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OemModelCode` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HasWarranty` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CertificationWarranty` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WarrantyMonth` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WarrantyMiles` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CertificationNumber` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ServiceContract` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InServiceDate` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CertificationDate` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateManufactured` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateCreated` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateUpdated` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateRemoved` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DatePhotosUpdated` varchar(19) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Photos` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SuperSizePhotos` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AddendumDetails` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DepartmentComments` varchar(239) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VehicleComments` varchar(1987) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Options` varchar(2264) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PurchasePayment` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PurchaseDownPayment` decimal(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PurchaseTerm` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PurchaseDisclosure` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PurchaseRate` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeasePayment` decimal(2,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeaseDownPayment` decimal(2,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeaseTerm` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeaseDisclosure` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeaseRate` decimal(2,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LeaseResidual` decimal(2,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved1` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved2` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved3` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved4` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved5` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Reserved6` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sitecert` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `VIN` (`VIN`),
  KEY `Make` (`Make`),
  KEY `StockNumber` (`StockNumber`),
  KEY `Model` (`Model`),
  KEY `Trim` (`Trim`),
  KEY `Body` (`Body`),
  KEY `VehicleClass` (`VehicleClass`),
  KEY `Transmission` (`Transmission`),
  KEY `DealerID` (`DealerID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=46527428 ;
```

And an example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM vehicles
WHERE Make = 'Audi'
    AND VehicleType = '0'
    AND Model = 'A4'
    AND InternetPrice BETWEEN 0 AND 999999
    AND Year BETWEEN 1983 AND 2015
    AND Mileage > 0
    AND DealerID IN ('AA'
        ,'156553'
        ,'229602'
        ,'160483'
        ,'2953'
        ,'161712'
        ,'228576'
        ,'228921'
        ,'7590'
        ,'20813'
        ,'158105'
        ,'160286'
        ,'164479'
        ,'164487'
        ,'182543'
        ,'158860'
        ,'186479'
        ,'227170'
        ,'226327'
        )
ORDER BY sitecert DESC
    ,InternetPrice DESC 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Would anyone have any advice to optimize this query or table? Of course there is other code throughout the page but I've timed it down to this query that is causing the delay.

Thanks for your help!

UPDATE:

MySQL Explain:

```
id select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  vehicles    ref Make,Model,DealerID Model   75  const   1675    Using where; Using filesort
```

Year was updated to INT

Comment: Have you looked at [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)?

Comment: Have you tried using `EXPLAIN` to see how the query is being processed?  In particular checking to see if its doing a full table scan.

Comment: What does an EXPLAIN on the query show?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija - I'll look into that. This table is truncated and updated nightly via CSV file. Do you think that will cause issues when separating the data via cron?

Comment: How big is the table ? rows!

Comment: @justacodeguy The cron will have to be update accordingly. Normalization is one of the first things that you should look into when optimizing your database. Then comes the basic `EXPLAIN` usage to identify bottlenecks.

Comment: I updated the question with the current `explain` data. I'll look into normalization. The table has 1,004,040 rows in it currently.

Comment: Normalization has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: what time does it take? 1600 rows seems fair amount to me.

Comment: How about making the table index-organized? This won't require to update an index on each write.

Comment: 1,600 rows is just an example with the criteria I selected. Essentially, the user will be able to narrow down the data just as you'd expect an advanced search to work on any classified website. The problem I'm having is returning those results when the search becomes more complexed when the user has more stringent criteria.. of which there could be 6-12 different columns being searched. The query adjusts based on what data the user has selected. If the user didn't select a certain field (Ex: mileage), then that is not added to the final query.

Comment: All the "adjustments" should not add to the query complexity above these 1600. Just more records will be filtered out - not a big deal. Is it a *real* problem you are really having, or you just "foresee" it and fear in advance?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your database, you should add indexes on the following fields:

```
Make
VehicleType
Model
InternetPrice
Year
Mileage
DealerId
```

Year should be DATE type, not text (INT also makes sense).

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Did you have the same question to solve and did this approach help?

Comment: This is how I'd do. Searching on text fields always harder than searching in numbers.

Comment: Bad idea ! The table load will take for ever ! after creating this indexes

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, it should have been an INT but slipped by me. I've played with the indexes in the past and couldn't find the improvement to be satisfactory, leading me to believe there's something more I can do to improve it.

Comment: Indexes **IS** the way to go. And as you state that the data is re-loaded every night simply drop the indexes first, truncate the table, load the new data and rebuild the indexes. It won't take all that long extra and the result of having the (proper, compound) indexes on the data will be that you'll have much faster queries during the day. PS: I'd also suggest to switch to InnoDb; MyIsam is for toying only (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

**My advices :**

- use a **group by make**
- partition your table, columns might be of use (make,Year)
- store your table in inndb engine instead of myisam and build your
  self some clustered indexes to attend your predicates !

Comment: How these things can help? Grouping practically

Comment: run a profile on this query and you will find out ! less I/O

Answer (score -1):

For such a case you have to read EXPLAIN results and tweak indexes accordingly.

However, for only 1600 rows to sort I wouldn't bother at all. If you still want to make it faster, it seems you need a combined key that would include a Model and a sitecert followed by price, both in a reverse order.

Means you have to have two additional columns where negative values of sitecert and price are stored. then buind an index on (Model,nsitecert, nInternetPrice) and order without DESC to eliminate a filesort

If you have search queries that involve no Model but any combination of parameters - then it's time to think of an external search engine like Sphinx Search.

Comment: ? I am so confused by your answer ! can you put this in database terms ? like what can he do mysql engine+ DML improved structure + order + grouped by + less I/O

Comment: All I did is proposed an index of the structure I described.

Comment: You said to use a group by out of nowhere.

Comment: I don't think the ORDER BY is going to be the culprit here but rather the WHERE. All this adding a new field to avoid a filesort sounds like techno-make-belief IMHO. Why would you try to scan 1M rows (to only keep less than 2k) in the right order when it's magnitudes faster to have a proper index to quickly find those 2k rows and then sort them afterwards as needed.

Comment: @deroby That's what I said.